# time() function php

Tags: php, time

Estou paginando algumas compras que tem datas especificas, e quando passo como parametro que uma data deve ser < que `date("Y-m-t", time() + 14*24*60*60)`, que no caso teria que ser 2 semanas, ele me pagina 1 mês. De acordo com o doc do php, `24*60*60` é 1 dia, logo `date("Y-m-t", time() + 14*24*60*60)` seria 14 dias/ 2 semanas. Alguém entender o porque disso?

Comment: Da data atual vc quer adicionar mais 14 dias?

Comment: isso, preciso pegar a data de hoje mais 14 dias, depois mais 1 mes, depois mais 2 meses..

Comment: As respostas resolvem isso? ou falta algo?

Comment: mais uma pergunta, no strtotime quando quero mais de uma semana, ou mes, eu tenho que colocar no plural? 2 weeks, 2 months ?

Comment: pode ser no singular, tanto faz.

Comment: então é isso. Todos minhas dúvidas foram sanadas. Obrigado à todos.

Comment: :D volte sempre!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se quiser utilizar apenas funções, `strftime()` e `strtotime()` resolvem também.

```
echo strftime('%Y-%m-%d', strtotime('+2 weeks'));
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, funcionou perfeitamente.

Answer (score 1):

Em vez de usar o `date()` você pode usar `DateTime` que possui vários métodos interessantes.

[Doc PHP - DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)

Usando o método `add()` - [Doc DateTime - Add](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php)

**Exemplo:**

```
$now = new DateTime();

echo $now->format('d/m/Y H:i:s'); // exibe 18/09/2015 10:12:40

echo '<br />';

$now->add(new DateInterval('P2W')); 

echo $now->format('d/m/Y H:i:s'); // exibe 02/10/2015 10:12:40
```